# How can I deploy the PrimeFaces Showcase in Payara/Glassfish?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, cdi, payara

I was trying to run the PrimeFaces Showcase in Payara(Fork of Glassfish) Server. I expected it to run in `localhost:8080` but failed.

Below is the error that I encountered:

```
Error occurred during deployment:
  Exception while loading the app : CDI definition failure:
    Exception List with 1 exceptions: 
      Exception 0 : 
        javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException 
          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
          at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
          at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
          at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
          at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:78)
          at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:96)
          at org.jboss.weld.injection.Method
          ....
          msg.seeServerLog
```

On the other hand, I run on jetty server and it's working fine.
I used the commands:
mvn clean                  -- clean temp files from target folder
mvn package                -- create war file (under target directory)
mvn jetty:run              -- run showcase project locally

Environment/Platform:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Java Version "1.8.0_131"
Eclipse Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Payara 4.1.173
```

Comment: Just as the message says, have a look at server.log, the reason(s) for the issue will be found there. It may be a bit lengthy, but it should prove more insightful than just this single line.

Comment: This gives an idea ... https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/issues/50